# Performing a complex self-referential query using the Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have the following model:

```
class Message(Model):
    url = URLField("URL")
    email = EmailField("E-Mail")
    contacted = BooleanField("Contacted", default=False)
```

With example data like:

```
| url | email           | contacted |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+
| foo | foo@example.com | N         |
| bar | bar@example.com | N         |
| baz | foo@example.com | Y         |
```

I would like to select all distinct rows (by e-mail address) whose e-mail addresses have never been contacted.  With this example data, the `bar@example.com` row would be the only one returned.

Comment: Why whould bar@example.com be the only one returned? Since foo@example.com has contacted set to False as well and is distinct.

Comment: @thikonom If an e-mail address has ever been contacted, it should not be included in the results.  That is the source of the problem.  ;)

Comment: I don't know django, but in sql this is almost trivial.

Comment: @wildplasser Could you give an answer with the SQL solution?

Comment: Yes, but there is one thing to clear up: if two or more records exist with the same email (but different url) and no records exists (for the same email) with contacted = 'y', which of them do you want to be returned by the query?

Comment: @wildplasser It actually doesn't really matter.  The "first" (either in natural sort or sorted by a timestamp field not shown in the example) would be good, but "all" is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the records you want:

```
not_contacted = Message.objects.exclude(
    email__in=Message.objects.filter(contacted=True).values('email')
)
```

This has the advantage of only running one query. Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT
    messages_message.id, messages_message.url, messages_message.email, messages_message.contacted
FROM
    Messages
WHERE NOT
    (messages_message.email IN
        ( SELECT U0.email from messages_message U0 WHERE U0.contacted = True )
    )
```

Note that for many, many records this query may not be optimal, but it will probably work for most uses.

Comment: Huzzah!  Thanks!  This is the Django version of @wildplasser's pure SQL solution.  Wish I could accept both.  :D

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE massage
        ( zurl varchar NOT NULL
        , zemail varchar NOT NULL
        , contacted boolean
        );
INSERT into massage(zurl, zemail, contacted) VALUES

( 'foo', 'foo@example.com', False)
,( 'bar', 'bar@example.com', False)
,( 'baz', 'foo@example.com', True)
        ;

SELECT
        DISTINCT zemail AS zemail
        , MIN(zurl) AS zurl
FROM massage m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM massage nx
        WHERE nx.zemail = m.zemail
        AND nx.contacted = True
        )
GROUP BY zemail;
```

If there are multiple records for a given email address, the above one picks the one with the "lowest" URL. If you want them all, the query would be even simpler:

```
SELECT m.zurl, m.zemail
FROM massage m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM massage nx
        WHERE nx.zemail = m.zemail
        AND nx.contacted = True
        ) ;
```